# Need to update duplicate with existing rows

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I need to update(clean) my data by following conditions

1. Check if **PS-id** has duplicate values.
2. Check which has the latest **Date**
3. Update the old row which has the latest **Date** and new **Cam** with the old **Cam**

   ```
   ID       Cam                PS-id             Date
   A1       Alto-Car           A1222             1.1.2022     
   B1       BMW-Car            A123              1.1.2022
   A5       Car-Alto           A1222             5.1.2022
   ```

The ideal output should be like this

```
ID       Cam                PS-id             Date
A1       Car-Alto           A1222             5.1.2022     
B1       BMW-Car            A123              1.1.2022
```

I have tried few solutions but cant do based on my conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to datetimes in column `Date`, then sorting per both columns, so first row is old rows created by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and converting to `Series` used for reassign `ID` by rows with maximal vaues per `PS-id`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m.%d.%Y')
df = df.sort_values(['PS-id','Date'])

s = df.drop_duplicates('PS-id').set_index('PS-id')['ID']
df = df.drop_duplicates('PS-id', keep='last').assign(ID = lambda x: x['PS-id'].map(s))
print (df)
   ID       Cam  PS-id       Date
2  A1  Car-Alto  A1222 2022-05-01
1  B1   BMW-Car   A123 2022-01-01
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want a combination of [`groupby`+`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`groupby`+`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), that you [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
# get indices of latest (max) dates
# here we keep the string format
# if you want to convert to datetime
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
idx = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).groupby(df['PS-id']).idxmax().values

# slice the rows with max dates
(df.loc[idx]
   # and merge back first id
   .merge(df.groupby('PS-id')['ID'].first(),
          left_on='PS-id', right_index=True, suffixes=('_', ''))
   .drop('ID_', axis=1)[df.columns]
)
```

output:

```
   ID       Cam  PS-id      Date
2  A1  Car-Alto  A1222  5.1.2022
1  B1   BMW-Car   A123  1.1.2022
```